# Are statements of the form "I claim that X" always true?

Tags: philosophy-of-language

Suppose I were to say that "I claim that I am the happiest person in the world.". Would that statement, and similar statements, be true? It does not state that I am indeed the happiest, only that I claim to be.

Comment: See [Performative utterance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Performative_utterance) and in particular the section on "true/false" and the reference to Searle given there.

Comment: The sentence is ambiguous unless you add a modifier like "sometimes", "always", or "at this very instant". In the last case, the statement is tautologically true. In the "always" case, it could be false (or become false). In the first case, it would require that you claimed at some point to be the happiest person in the world-- simply saying that you sometimes claim it isn't sufficient.

Comment: No. One can be lying or mistaken about what the utterance means, or even about what they truly believe, at least on some conceptions. The idea that "we always know how we feel" is based on Cartesian dualistic view of mind/body relation with "privileged" access to our own "self-transparent" mind. This picture is considered too naive today, see [Opacity of Mind](http://ndpr.nd.edu/news/the-opacity-of-mind-an-integrative-theory-of-self-knowledge).

Comment: Answer is "no" iff there's a statement in that form that's not true. Are there examples?

What if you fill in "X" with meaningless, ungrammatical nonsense? Example: "I claim that are bees times in was." Is that statement true? It is iff the speaker claims that "are bees times in was". But how can one claim that? The speaker is not claiming anything, so the statement is not true. (Alternatively: you could say the speaker is indeed making a claim, just a meaningless one.)

A narrower question would be: "Are there any meaningful statements of the form 'I claim that X' that are not true?"